# Where to initialize module specific variables

Tags: hooks, sessions

I have been using hook_init in order to initialize some _SESSION variables on my application, however a problem I got after... is that hook_init is called on every ajax request. That's why I wanted to ask, what other hook, function or method should I use in order to initialize my module specific variables. I'm looking for something that's called just the first time the user enters the page, and not when a submit button is launched. (similar to isPostback???).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hook_init()` is always invoked for not cached pages, even for AJAX request. You can verify the page request is made because an AJAX request, though.

There are two conditions that should be common on any AJAX request:

- The menu path is system/ajax
- The delivery callback is [ajax_deliver()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/function/ajax_deliver/7)

While the first condition is only true when the form element doesn't set [#ajax['path']](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax),  the second condition should always be true.

Code similar to the following one should detect when a menu callback is called because an AJAX request.

```
if ($router_item = menu_get_item()) {
  if (isset($route_item['delivery_callback']) && $route_item['delivery_callback'] == 'ajax_deliver') {
    // It is an AJAX call.
  }
}
```

In Drupal 6, the menu callback for AJAX/AHAH requests changes, and each menu has its own callback. You can notice the path for those menu callbacks follows a specific pattern: It usually ends with /js, but that is not necessarily true. This means a menu callback could be associated with a path ending with /js, but that menu callback is not for a AJAX/AHAH request.

Comment: Does this work on Drupal 6?, if not what could be another way to simulate a "View Scope" in drupal??

Comment: In Drupal 6, there aren't delivery callbacks. You can check the path associated with the current page, but you can be 100% the request is because an AJAX/AHAH request, if you checking the output of the menu callback.

Answer (score 1):

Quickest way in your `hook_init()` might be to set a semaphore, eg,

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['foo'])) {
  // set your variables here
  $_SESSION['foo']=TRUE;
}
```

would do it for the length of the user's entire session, or,

```
if (isset($_SESSION['foo']) && $_SESSION['foo']!=$_GET['q']) {
  // set your page specific variables here
  $_SESSION['foo']=$_GET['q'];
}
```

the first time the user went to a specific page, and would clear/reset when s/he went to a different page afterwards, etc.

You could also look into

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_user/6

if you wanted to do it just when your user first logs in as well.

Comment: What does the $_GET['q'] variable do? Is it set by Drupal or where should I set it?

Comment: $_GET['q'] is the system path/query string inside drupal.  For example, if you are at `yourhost.com/my/fantastic/content_listing` it would be set to `my/fantastic/content_listing` but realize it is the system path, not a path alias, so, it might be `node/127` instead.  It is set by Drupal.

Comment: Didn't worked as expected, since $_GET['q'] is changed even when ajax calls are executed... so in that case, initialization code is not correct.